# I am trying to load external JSON VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am somewhat new to all this so please bear with me. i am using SurveyJS to render a survey from a JSON file. I can get it to work locally but when I add a component to load the JSON into an object everything breaks down. I'm not sure what I need to do next. Do I need anything in the  section of the loading component? Am I passing the data correctly between components? I am at a loss...

Here is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>


<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Here is my router.js:

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
import SurveyPage from '@/components/SurveyPage'
import newSurvey from '@/components/getNewSurvey.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'SurveyPage',
      component: SurveyPage
    }
  ]
})
```

Here is my main app SurveyPage.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
  
    <div id='surveyElement'>
      <survey :survey="surveyModel"/>
      <div id="surveyResult"></div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as SurveyVue from 'survey-vue'
import surveyJSON from '@/assets/survey.json'
import newSurvey from '@/components/getNewSurvey.vue'

let Survey = SurveyVue.Survey

export default {
  name: 'SurveyPage',
  components: {
    Survey
  },
  computed: {
    surveyModel () {
      let survyeModel = new SurveyVue.Model(surveyData)
      survyeModel.onComplete.add(function (result) {
        //document
        //.queryselector('#surveyResult')
        //.textContent = "Result JSON:\n" + JSON.stringify(result.data);

      alert(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result.data)}`)
      })
      
      return survyeModel
    }
  }
  
  
}
</script>
```

and here is the new component that I want to use to load the JSON before rendering the survey called getNewSurvey.vue:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "newSurvey",
  data() {
    return {
      surveyData: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getSurveyData() {
      fetch('http://localhost:8081/survey.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => (this.surveyData = data));
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.getSurveyData()
  }
};
</script>
```

Here is the cosole output:

```
**DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/contentscript.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/sourcemaps/inpage.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
log.js?1afd:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:601 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: surveyData is not defined"
found in
---> <SurveyPage> at src/components/SurveyPage.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>
warn @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:601
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1828
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1823
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1812
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4655
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4239
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5688
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5635
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5763
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5664
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2778
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4239
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5688
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5635
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6226
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2778
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
eval @ main.js?56d7:12
./src/main.js @ app.js:2460
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
fn @ app.js:101
0 @ app.js:2485
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
(anonymous) @ app.js:791
(anonymous) @ app.js:794
Show 10 more frames
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1832 ReferenceError: surveyData is not defined
    at VueComponent.surveyModel (SurveyPage.vue?8ee1:26)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3374)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as surveyModel] (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3626)
    at Object.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2025)
    at Proxy.render (eval at ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?{"cacheDirectory":"node_modules\\.cache\\vue-loader","cacheIdentifier":"52009d03-vue-loader-template"}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js?!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/SurveyPage.vue?vue&type=template&id=2ec8a28e&scoped=true& (app.js:1174), <anonymous>:13:45)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4653)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258)
logError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1832
globalHandleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1823
handleError @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1812
Vue._render @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4655
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4239
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5688
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5635
createChildren @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5763
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5664
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6187
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2778
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
init @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4239
createComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5688
createElm @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5635
patch @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6226
Vue._update @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2778
updateComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2899
get @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3269
Watcher @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3258
mountComponent @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2906
Vue.$mount @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:8070
eval @ main.js?56d7:12
./src/main.js @ app.js:2460
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
fn @ app.js:101
0 @ app.js:2485
__webpack_require__ @ app.js:724
(anonymous) @ app.js:791
(anonymous) @ app.js:794
Show 9 more frames
inpage.js:1 MetaMask: MetaMask will soon stop reloading pages on network change.
For more information, see: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#ethereum-autorefreshonnetworkchange 
Set 'ethereum.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange' to 'false' to silence this warning.
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
setTimeout (async)
t.exports @ inpage.js:1
initProvider @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
1../lib/setupWeb3 @ inpage.js:1
i @ inpage.js:1
e @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ inpage.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
1.@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireDefault @ contentscript.js:1
i @ contentscript.js:1
e @ contentscript.js:1
(anonymous) @ contentscript.js:1
```

Comment: what error is printed in the console? how does it "breaks down"?

Comment: Here is the log file and thank you so much for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Ur arrow function is not well defined, since you will be using variables from outside the direct scope of the function you should define its body, it cannot be inline as the `response => response.json()`, then you should write it like this

```js
getSurveyData() {
  fetch('http://localhost:8081/survey.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.surveyData = data
    }
  );
}
```

Comment: Still not working. Now I am getting this error: cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/getNewSurvey.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:1 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\guardian\sytapp\src\components\getNewSurvey.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (20:2)

Comment: src/components/getNewSurvey.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\guardian\sytapp\src\components\getNewSurvey.vue: Unexpected token, expected "," (20:2)

  18 |         this.surveyData = data
  19 |     }
> 20 |   };
     |   ^
  21 |   
  22 |   beforeMount() {
  23 |     this.getSurveyData()
    at _class.raise